# How to redirect "/%20rel="?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

The following redirect isn't working, I assume it's because of the characters in the page name (generated by Wordpress).

```
redirect 301 /%20rel= http://www.NewSite.com/OldSiteLandingPage.php
```

How can I get this 301 redirect from "/%20rel=" to work?

Comment: Try to put there space character instead of %20

Comment: What is URL of the page you're trying to redirect?

Comment: Google is giving me a Crawl Error for the page "/%20rel="  (www.mywebsite.com/%20rel=).  This is one of many odd pages left over from a WordPress installation on another website that I ended up closing and forwarding to my main website.  I was able to clear up all the other Crawl Errors with the 301 redirect, but this one isn't working.

Comment: I tried putting a space where the %20 is, but it took my entire website down:  500 Internal Server Error.  I guess because the / was there by itself with a space after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
Redirect 301 "/ rel=" /
```

Comment: That did it.  When I replaced the %20 with a space it took my site down.  But when I put quotes around it like you said, it works perfectly.  Thanks everyone.